# Who pays the upkeep on gifted units?

Tags: civilization-5

Is it the civ/CS who receives it, the giver, or no-one? Also, can you gift unit's to people on your team?

Comment: It wouldn't let me post the question so I had to add something. I took off the last part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maintenance costs for units are paid based on the units that a civilization currently owns. When you gift away a unit, you stop paying maintenance costs immediately, meaning your costs will be decreased before the start of your next turn, which is when you will next pay maintenance. When the receiving unit gains the new units, they will then see their maintenance costs increase. During any time in-between, the unit will not be owned by anyone (nor even be on the map), and so will incur no maintenance costs for any civilization or city-state.

Comment: So you could make someone go bankrupt by gifting them a lot of units? Could you also have a large standing army with low maintenance cost by gifting them back and forth to people on your team/allies?

Comment: The person who receives the unit can always disband it.

Comment: "Could you also have a large standing army with low maintenance cost by gifting them back and forth to people on your team/allies?"

Yes, but the army will be locked up in transit a lot; you'd need advance warning to actually have them ready to use. And it'd take a lot of coordinating. And you'd still pay maintenance on each unit once every time it reappeared.